# Matplotlib/Pandas to generate specific graph from Python dict/JSON

Tags: json, excel, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I'm looking to make a specific graph layout from a specific **format** of **Python** data, but where the **data may be text, string, or another Python object**.

I can do this with XlsxWriter (see below), but the data overloads it (14 million lines...no joke. DNA data). Is it possible/how can I do this with Matplotlib or PAndas (or more stable with large data)?

DETAILS:
It has to be able to do it on the **fly**, and make visual formatting decisions based on whether the data is "the same" (regardless of numerically, text or another Python object).

***The coloring in the cells*** is based on whether the items within `{1:"A", 2:"A"}`are **equivalent** (not the same object). **Green** for `True`, **red** for `False`. For example: `"A" == "A"` (as in the preceding sentences), or `(10/5) == (20/10)`, or `["A", 1, <test object at 0x1052c9b70>] == ["A", 1, <test object at 0x1052c9b70>]` would all be green.

The text that appears in the cells is just the __str__ representation of the object.

EXAMPLE ...

```
{
    1000:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          },

    1001:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"}
          },

    1002:{
          "Sample1":{1:"C", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"}
          },

    (...)

    9999:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"T"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"G"}
          },
}
```

[image: Excel example]

Comment: Are you aware of the closing reason: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*? So you would like to edit your question to decide for one tool and show an attempt of a solution (or indicate the actual problem of using this tool).

Comment: I understand. But, to be honest, I was hoping to avoid spending 1 or 2 hours learning enough matpoltlib, only to discover it can't do this. And then again with another tool. And another. Is there a ```Stack exchange```forum where this type of opinion question IS appropriate?

Comment: Maybe you want to see it from an answerer's perspective. He would not want to spend half an hour on a solution just to find out that it is then not using the appropriate tool for you. (I know you said it wouldn't matter, but is that honest? Almost every time I answered such a question a comment later said, "That's great, but I cannot use it, because of reason bla.", where "bla" had in no way been mentionned in the question.) E.g. here I might opt for a solution using pandas formatted tables in a Jupyter notebook. Would that solution be appropriate?

Comment: Fair enough. I changed to ask if this can be done with Matplotlib or Pandas. There really is a problem with the XLS version because its such a huge volume of data. I know Numpy can handle large arrays...but not with that type of data. I dont know matplotlib or pandas well enough. 

Honestly, if I can just get a reassurance that matplotlib COULD do it...then I'll take the time to learn how. I dont even need live code (but I'll take it if offered :D)

Comment: "E.g. here I might opt for a solution using pandas formatted tables in a Jupyter notebook. Would that solution be appropriate?"

If you think that actually might work...I'll try it :D Honestly, I need the report. HOW is not material to my boss :) So, I'm unconstrained (except for buying a $10,000 piece of software or something :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas and styled tables in a Jupyter notebook:

```
json = {
    1000:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          },
    1001:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"}
          },
    1002:{
          "Sample1":{1:"C", 2:"A"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"A"}
          },
    9999:{
          "Sample1":{1:"A", 2:"T"}, 
          "Sample2":{1:"A", 2:"A"},
          "Sample3":{1:"A", 2:"G"}
          },
}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(json).transpose()
df0 = df.applymap(lambda x: "{}/{}".format(x[1].__repr__(),x[2].__repr__()))
df0

df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: x[2])

booldf = df1 == df2
c = lambda x : 'background-color: {}'.format(x)
formatdf = booldf.applymap(lambda x: c("limegreen") if x else c("crimson"))

df0.style.apply(lambda x: formatdf, axis=None)
```

[image]